# K9-Mail does not detect PGP encrypted mail automatically

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, custom-roms, encryption, k9-mail

I have a bit of a problem with PGP and K9-Mail on my Galaxy S3.
I'm using the GPG Mail plugin on my computer (Mac OS X 10.8) and can read and write mails just perfectly.

Today I decided to setup PGP on my phone. It's rooted and runs the ParandoidAndroid 3.55 custom mod. I did the setup as shown in this guide: http://cariadus.com/blog/2010/07/how-to-set-up-your-android-phone-to-enable-sending-pgp-signed-emails-to-nominets-automaton/
and everything went fine.

I can encrypt and decrypt mails sent from my phone (to myself). BUT, here is the problem. As soon as I send myself (or got a mail from a friend) that wasn't sent via K9-Mail and Android it doesn't recognize the signature. FOllowing screenshot will explain:

[image: Screenshot]

It shows me the attachments but the usual "Decrypt" button that I get from mails sent from my phone itself doesn't show up. I update my public key + the public key from the friend that sent me a mail from the keyserver and have both of them stored in APG.

Well, I hope you understand my problem now and have advice on what I can do to fix this :P Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem when sending encrypted mails from my Apple Mail client with GPGMail2 plug-in.

Apparently K9-Mail supports only PGP/Inline and not PGP/MIME which seems to be the standard formatting PGP-Emails today.

If you like to test it on your own, configure GPGMail to use inline mode through your Terminal:

```
defaults write org.gpgtools.gpgmail UseOpenPGPInlineToSend -bool YES
```

[Reference](http://support.gpgtools.org/kb/faq-gpgmail/gpgmail-2-hidden-settings).

There is an [open feature request](https://code.google.com/p/k9mail/issues/detail?id=5864) to address this issue. Hopefully, the K9 developers will fix this soon. So, **consider starring this issue**.

Comment: I have created a small bounty for the same issue: https://www.bountysource.com/issues/815255-pgp-mime

Comment: Here is a newer feature request for PGP/MIME: https://github.com/k9mail/k-9/issues/576

Answer (score 2):

As linnedude mentions, this is a problem of K-9 mail. There is a [pgp/mime milestone](https://github.com/k9mail/k-9/milestones/PGP/MIME) on github with the issues to be fixed.